# How param works in rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an old app running in rails 2.3.5
In customizing, I stuck when i find a param keyword being used in views
i.e in views I can see stuffs like

```
 unless params[:fee_collection].nil?
```

can someone explain to me in what context is param keyword used in rail views rather than controllers

Answer (score 1):

**params** is a hash that contains parameters sent with the HTTP request.

You can access to this object as well from your controller or from a view. Although, the convention is to access to an instance variable (defined in your controller, e.g : @fee_collection = params[:fee_collection]) from your view.

Answer (score 0):

The params variable stores a hash which contains the http parameters received in the request to this route (controller#action)

If you have a UserController with the show method, you should receive the param[:id] to identify the resource you're looking for.

If you want to send parameters, it would be either via url in a GET or a data payload on a POST request, on the most common cases.